# JFreeChart ChartPanel resizes on content change

Tags: java, layout, resize, jfreechart, chartpanel

I am using a `ChartPanel` from JFreeChart (1.0.14) to display some plots. The Layout is handled by [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) and all works well. However, I have strange behaviour from time to time. The minimal size of the panel changes sometimes when the plots change. I am not setting it in my code but leave everything to MigLayout.

Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce this behaviour in an SSCCE, especially the first S. But in my application it also occurs when I am just changing the renderer to display a thicker line for one of the `XYSeries`.

So my question:

- **Is it possible that the layout parameters are changed within the code of JFreeChart depending on the displayed content?**
- **If so, is it possible to turn off this behaviour?** Because I don't want anything else than MigLayout to lay hands on the layout parameters...

Comment: I've not seen this with other layouts; sorry, I don't use MigLayout. `JFreeChart` itself is _not_ a `JComponent`; it _has_ no layout. Except for calling `setPreferredSize()` in the common constructor, `ChartPanel` is reasonably well-behaved.

Comment: @trashgod Hm, that's not it. I try to create an SSCCE, but I don't know if I succeed... Let you know. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I'll be glad to give it a whirl; ping me so I'll see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem. My `ChartPanel` is in a `TabbedPane` with other tabs. One of those other tabs also contains charts. And one of those charts has a logarithmic range axis. Now I put in data that contained negative values, which can not be displayed logarithmically and the reaction of the axis was to just zoom out in both directions as much as possible. This resulted in extremly long axis labels (`0.0000000[..]00001 and 10000[..]0000`). This resulted in MigLayout giving more space to this panel and recursively also demanding more space from the tabbed pane. So the tabbed pane grew also for my other tabs.

Quiet strange and hard to figure out... ;) Thanks to trashgod for your willingness to help. :)